# JAVA REGEX does not split accordingly

Tags: java, regex

EDITED

When I define a string like

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = reader.next();
String[] code = input.split(" ");
for(String splits : code){
    System.out.println(splits);
}
```

the output is

```
This
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nice you showed us the code that works. More interesting however is the code that doesn't. More likely the error is in there don't you think?

Comment: I know that it works. I just don't understand why it splits perfectly when using static variable and not when it is defined by a user.

Comment: @Henry is right you must include the code that doesn't work. Else we have to write the code from beginning rather than finding errors in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `nextLine();` to get the line input from user. It will be good for you to [follow this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Change your code to this. I have tested this one it's working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        String[] code = input.split(" ");
        for(String splits : code){
            System.out.println(splits);
        }
    }
```

Input : `This is a heading` 
Output :

```
This
is
a
heading
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps or you find it useful